# ASP MVC 4 deployment in server - how to assign domain name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, domain-name

I am a beginner of developing an ASP MVC 4 application. I have my application deployed on my server, but I wanted to assign a domain name on it. Is it possible?

I currently deployed it as with ip address when accessing the application.
eg: 141.201.0.235:81 in port 81

But I wanted it as something like http://www.MyApp.com

Comment: Off-topic. Finding instruction on how to buy/obtain domain name is really outside of scope for SO.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thanks man, that's why i am a beginner of website deployments and ASKING IF ITS POSSIBLE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be reachable via a domain name for real, you'll need to buy a domain name from a Domain Name Registrar, which requires an annual fee.

Then, using a DNS hosting service or your own DNS server, you'll need to direct www.[yourdomainhere].com and [yourdomainhere].com to the public facing IP address of your web server running your web application.

If it's the only application on the machine with minimal configuration, it'll need to run on port 80.  However, most web servers including IIS can be configured to recognize what domain name the traffic is coming from and redirect from port 80 to whatever port your web application is actually running on.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I dont know those things at first. Thank you for the info.